# How to prevent child div moving when adding text to parent?

Tags: html

I have a basic HTML showing the safe zones used in broadcast. However, when I add text to the divs I have set up, it throws the alignment out of place.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="browserClock.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="safeAction">Safe Action Area
        <div id="safeText">Safe Text Area
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

html {
    width: 1920px;
    height: 1080px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: 0 0;
}
#safeAction {
    width: 1786px;
    height: 1003px;
    margin: 37px 66px 37px 66px;
    border: 1px dashed white;
}
#safeText {
    width: 1728px;
    height: 971px;
    margin: 16px 28px 16px 28px;
    border: 1px dotted white;
}
```

Without the text, it lines up as per the EBU standard pixel spacing. With text it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the inner div with id `safeText` is positioned relative to the other contents of the div it is in. To fix this, set the position of `safeText` to absolute and use `top` to set the the distance from the top of the inner div to the top of the outer div (in your case 16px) instead of the top-margin. Finally, give the body relative positioning so that it is determined a parent.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gf6q7f0c/)

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: 0 0;
    position: relative;
}
#safeAction {
    width: 1786px;
    height: 1003px;
    margin: 37px 66px 37px 66px;
    border: 1px dashed white;
}
#safeText {
    width: 1728px;
    height: 971px;
    margin: 0px 28px 16px 28px;
    border: 1px dotted white;
    top: 16px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Appreciate the help.